# look up value from another sql table in c# winforms

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using c# winform, When the users input something in State field I want to look up that value in another table and find that code. I have commented the line below on what I have tried but that has not worked

```
 MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(" update `STUDENT REGISTER` INNER JOIN `States` ON `STUDENT REGISTER`.`State` = `States`.`State Code` set " +
                "`first Name`='" + cboStudentFirstName.Text.Trim() + "'," +
                 "`Surname`='" + cboStudentSurname.Text.Trim() + "'," +
```

//if the person selects inputs VIC on this table I want it to look up that value in a table called states and bring me back the code for that state
                     "`STUDENT REGISTER`.`State`= `States`.`State Code`," +

Comment: How does it not work? Are you getting error? Did you try running the same query directly against the database?

Comment: Dont create SQL queries that way.  Use parameters.  Its less dangerouys, less tedious and less error prone

Comment: @Plutonix - what does use parameters mean and why is it less dangerous. It's my first time working with c# and SQL.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya when I run this code direct - nothing happens the state fields just doesn't update.  Here is the sql code update `STUDENT REGISTER` 
INNER JOIN `States` ON `STUDENT REGISTER`.`State` = `States`.`State Code`
set `first Name`="John",
`STUDENT REGISTER`.`State`= `States`.`State Code`
where `STUDENT NUMBER` = 7